# How to get the length of alpha-numeric characters in a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I wonder whether or not there is a function in PHP to count the length of alpha-numeric characters in a string in PHP. For example, assume that there are two variables `$var1 = 'aa12dA]]}}}?AWQ  Q'` and `$var2 = 'W  aQ14dA]]q}}?esd'`, so as you can see number of non alpha-numeric characters in `$var1` is greater than `$var2`. So, is there a function (perhaps something similar to `strlen()`) to compare the `$var1` and `$var2` in an if statement.

Comment: While there is a lot of nonsense functions in PHP, that one is not there. Luckily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just strip the characters you don't want to count, and run `strlen` on the result.

```
strlen(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string))
```

Comment: In other words, OP needs to learn how to use basic tools, and not expect to find a finished product for everything. +1.

Answer (score 3):

```
function countAlphaNum($str)
{
    return strlen(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $str));
}

if (countAlphaNum($var1) > countAlphaNum($var2))
{
    return 'var1 has more characters than var2';
}
```